# Spring MVC: how to avoid duplicating validation at controller and entity

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, security

Let's say I have a "Person" `@Entity` managed via JPA, which has a series of validations applied at entity-level (`@NotBlank, @NotNull` etc).

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @NotBlank
    private String name;

    @Email
    private String email;

    ...
}
```

For various reasons, we shouldn't directly use an entity as the controller method argument, but rather create a custom "form" (taking the example from https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/)

```
@PostMapping("/person/save")
public String savePerson(@Valid PersonForm personForm, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    // map fields to Person entity individually and save
    ...
}
```

But now, to make use of Spring's built-in form validation / `BindingResult`, it appears I have to duplicate all my validation logic on both the Person and PersonForm classes. I don't just want to define them on PersonForm, because there might be other routes in the application to update a Person.

Ideally there would be some way that Spring could lift up the validation constraints on the `@Entity` and apply them to the form (e.g. if the properties had the same name).

Am I missing something here with validation?